# How to change encoding of text box value

Tags: c#, encoding, textbox

I have a C# form Text Box and expect english or greek characters. 
I cannot properly display the greek characters. 
I am converting the encoding to code page 1253 as follows:

```
byte[] responseBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1253).GetBytes(myTextBox.Text);
message = Encoding.GetEncoding(1253).GetString(responseBytes);
```

The result is not the expected one for greek characters (no problems with the english ones).
Given character 'τ' appears as 'Δ', given character 'υ' appears as 'Ε', etc. 
Looking in the [codepage table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1253), seems like the conversion matches character F_1 to C_1, F_2 to C_2, etc. 
Is there something wrong in the way I am converting the encoding?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Unicode (UTF-8) as your display and storage encoding. I believe that will handle just about anything.

Comment: I changed encoding to UTF-8 and the result is the same. ''ψωχτ" is displayed as "ΘΙΗΔ"

Comment: Is that after you store the string somewhere? If so, where? DB? File? What is the table/file encoding?

Comment: I am displaying the string on a pinpad. On the pinpad side, I have properly set it to display extended ASCII characters.

Comment: Ah ha! Does the pad support multibyte encoding?

Comment: I think that's what's happening here, I think you're off by a register. For example, ψ is u+03c7 and Θ is u+03b7, so for whatever reason, you're not getting into the correct, uh, register? I didn't know how much trouble greek was, but at without the vendor API, I'm useless at this point.

Some things to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Greek_in_Unicode

http://www.unicode.org/faq/greek.html

Comment: I have asked the vendor if multibyte encoding is supported, will also read the above links. Thank you Lucas for all the help so far!